# Tkinter Text widget - Use clicked text in event function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, textbox

I currently have a a log parser that puts user infomration into a Text widget. If a line that is inserted into the Text widget has a keyword the line will be highlighted blue. If that line is clicked i'd like to use the text from that line in the event function that carries out.

Because I am using the config for my tag to color the line blue, am I not able to also copy the clicked text?

Example of the code:

```
from tkinter import *


def callback(event):
    window = Toplevel()
    window.overrideredirect(1)
    window.geometry("200x100+{0}+{1}".format(event.x_root-1, event.y_root-12))
    label = Label(window, justify="left", text="Username: value \nLocation: value \nAddress: value \nSecurity Level: value")
    label.grid()
    window.bind("<Leave>", lambda e: window.destroy())

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(END, "Click here", "tag")
text.pack()
text.tag_config("tag", foreground="blue")
text.tag_bind("tag", "<Button-1>", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I take the username that is clicked and use it in the function? I just want to set the username to a variable and use that, im just missing how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use individual tag for every clicked text and then you can send it as argument to binded function

```
import tkinter as tk


def callback(event, tag):
    print(event.widget.get('%s.first'%tag, '%s.last'%tag))

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

text.tag_config("tag1", foreground="blue")
text.tag_bind("tag1", "<Button-1>", lambda e:callback(e, "tag1"))
text.insert(END, "first link", "tag1")

text.insert(END, " other text ")

text.tag_config("tag2", foreground="blue")
text.tag_bind("tag2", "<Button-1>", lambda e:callback(e, "tag2"))
text.insert(END, "second link", "tag2")

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

I found how to convert mouse position and find clicked tag so it doesn't need individual tags.

[Python TKinter get clicked tag in text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33957256/1832058)

```
import tkinter as tk


def callback(event):
    # get the index of the mouse click
    index = event.widget.index("@%s,%s" % (event.x, event.y))

    # get the indices of all "adj" tags
    tag_indices = list(event.widget.tag_ranges('tag'))

    # iterate them pairwise (start and end index)
    for start, end in zip(tag_indices[0::2], tag_indices[1::2]):
        # check if the tag matches the mouse click index
        if event.widget.compare(start, '<=', index) and event.widget.compare(index, '<', end):
            # return string between tag start and end
            print(start, end, event.widget.get(start, end))

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

text.tag_config("tag", foreground="blue")
text.tag_bind("tag", "<Button-1>", callback)

text.insert(END, "first link", "tag")

text.insert(END, " other text ")

text.insert(END, "second link", "tag")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I had to ready the callback 3 or 4 times to understand what it was doing exactly. This handles everything I needed.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't create a second instance of `Tk`. If you need a popup window,  create an instance of `Toplevel`. You also don't need to call `mainloop` a second time.

You can get the index that was clicked on by using the x,y coordinate that you clicked on. For example: `text.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))`

Comment: I was throwing the example together from stuff I copied in other threads and I didn't notice the second mainloop or the seconds instance of Tk. Normally wouldn't do that but thanks for pointing them out. I'll fix the example.

Comment: Getting the index would give me the location of the word(s) but how to I select the word to set it as a variable?

Comment: @sidnical: you add the tag `sel` to whatever region you want to be selected.